# javascript errors when i call a function with String as parameter

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

can you tell me what I'm doing bad? I'm calling a javascript function from a html page managed by laravel but it returns me all time `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` or `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` when I put in between quotation marks the return of `$connexio->dispositiu->descendents()["credencial"]`.

`$connexio->dispositiu->descendents()["credencial"]` returns me that:

```
return [
        [
            'id' => 22,
            'tipus' => 'Antena',
            'name' => 'Ubikiti',
            'tab' => 0,
            'credencial' => "'".Dispositiu::find(22)->credencial->__toString()."'"
        ],......
```

`Dispositiu::find(22)->credencial->__toString()` returns me the next:

```
{
    $text = "IP: $this->ip:$this->port\n".
        "IP Interna: $this->ip_interna\n".
        "User: $this->user\n".
        "Password: $this->pass\n".
        "Observacions: $this->observacio\n\n".
        $this->credenciable->__toString();
    return $text;
}
```

The next code is in the html page.

```
<?php $comptador = 2 ?>
@foreach($connexio->dispositiu->descendents() as $fill)
    <tr class="<?php if($comptador%2 == 0) echo 'par'; else echo'impar'; $comptador++;?>"
        title="{{ $fill["credencial"] }}">
        <td class="connexioTab{{$fill["tab"]}} ">{{$fill["tipus"]}}</td>
        <td class="connexioTab{{$fill["tab"]}} ">{{$fill["name"]}}</td>
        <td>
            <a onclick="mostraInformacio({{ $fill["credencial"]}})"><i class="fa fa-unlock" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

The javascript function is:

```
function mostraInformacio(info){
    if(typeof info === "undefined") info = 'No credential found!';
    console.log(info);
    alert(info);
}
```

Can you tell me what is the error? When I execute `dd($fill["credencial");` it returns me the String, but between 6 quotation marks `""" String.... """`. Can be that the error?

Comment: If your question is about JavaScript: Why are you showing us PHP?

Comment: Because I'm using laravel framework, that works with php. But I'm calling a javascript function

Comment: So? You need to show us a [mcve]. Presumably, the PHP outputs some HTML and JS which doesn't work. Show us the HTML and JS instead of the PHP which generates it.

Comment: Ok, I'm new in StackOverflow. The next time I will do that. But now the javascript code, php returns and html code is showed. Do you need to watch some more of my code? Especify what more do you need pease, i will aport it now

Comment: First of all, don't use quotation marks like that, `"mostraInformacio({{ $fill["credencial"]}})"` should be `"mostraInformacio({{ $fill['credencial']}})" `and like so for every other situation related to that. You have the same mistake twice above inside the html page. That could theoretically cause errors, check that and report back.

Comment: Ok, I did that. It wasn't the error but it's good to know it

Comment: @axsor where are you getting this error. Is it from laravel side or javascript side? If it is from laravel side you can see stack trace to find out error and if it is from javascript you can see console which will show you the line number.

Comment: I get the 2 errors (`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` and `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`) at the chrome console, when i click the icon that has the "onclick" parameter. But the console gives me the line number error to the tag that calls the js file functions. I'm sure that the problem is the form that i pass the string as parameter to js function. But I don't know how to resolve that. I tried to convert to string the text before pass it to function, to add quotation marks before pass it to the function, but I can't...

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. It was in my PHP code,`__toString()` method of 'Dispositiu->credencial' had code similar like this:

```
$text = "IP: $this->ip:$this->port\n".
    "IP interna: $this->ip_interna\n".
    "User: $this->user\n".
    "Pass: $this->pass\n".
    "Observació: $this->observacio\n".
    $this->credenciable->__toString();
return $text;
```

I changed the form to input new lines to this:

```
$text = "IP: $this->ip:$this->port".'\n'.
    "IP interna: $this->ip_interna".'\n'.
    "User: $this->user".'\n'.
    "Pass: $this->pass".'\n'.
    "Observació: $this->observacio".'\n\n'.
    $this->credenciable->__toString();
return $text;
```

And it works, I can see the string into alert javascript.

Thanks to all who tried to help me.